# Recent Interview Q - Manipulate Objects on Page for Multiple Users?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

If this isn't appropriate, I apologize, but I wanted to get some feedback on a question I was recently asked during a phone interview. I'm strong on front end development but not very clear on back end programming, something I am trying to remedy.

After I got off the call, I had a bit of *l'esprit de l'escalier*, I think...

> Here's the scenario: You have a simple page where a user is presenting
>   with a random image and allowed to move it around the page, at the
>   same time that user can see other users of the same page who are also
>   moving around their own random images, but no one is allowed to
>   interact with any other user's images.

So, assuming the **LAMP** stack is in play and **jQuery / JavaScript** for your front end, describe how you would implement this and prevent these users from taking control of the objects. Assume the users are savvy enough to watch the post calls in firebug.

I was able to describe a simple interface and control. I was able to describe streaming coordinates to and from a database.

I struggled a bit to think of a good way to protect the information being retrieved while on the call.

After I was off the call, within moments, I thought about a simple method of preventing others from gaining control of this data by not exposing the actual IDs of the objects within the database from which they are called. But I'm still not certain of how to do this exactly. I imagine using a **php** engine to abstract the variable calls, using random Ids on the objects each user cannot interact with.

This is not something that I have ever considered when working with **php / MySQL**, but of course I'm thinking that I probably should, even when beating an open source **CMS** or something into submission.

So, my question is if someone could describe their own thoughts on this or point me to a resource to help me grok this, and how I would use **AJAX / PHP** to make this work? Am I on the right track?

I haven't heard if I got the job yet, but though it seems it was a primarily front end role, I think they wanted a bit more familiarity with the LAMP than I was able to demonstrate.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Yes, I will be following up with this on my own, and I'm already putting together some plans to dig deeper into **php** and **MySQL** for my own edification.

Answer (score 2):

I just took this up as a challenge myself, to try out new technology, and I found it a quite fun little thing to work on. The approach I took was in **node.js** using **mongodb** as storage.

Using **socket.io**, the manipulating was set up pretty fast. As for protecting the objects from external I relied on the session ID, which I linked to the object ID. This way, you can safely expose the ID of the object without it getting compromised.

Do note that the manipulating is limited to following the other cursors on the same page.

http://gist.github.com/ThomasHambach/5168951

Comment: Not an exact implementation of the question as described, but as it's all in pretty plain JavaScript it's pretty easy to read and see what you did. I appreciate that. I've been looking into Node.js and how it can be used for small scale interactions, this is a great example of that as well. Thank you very much.